# Low resolution rasterize in Mathematica Online

Tags: front-end, wolfram-cloud

On Mathematica Online/Wolfram Cloud, some graphics like `Tree` plots aren't rendered as vector graphics but are instead rasterized. However, on my high DPI (2256x1504, 200 ppi) screen, the raster resolution is very low:

[image: Graph and Tree output with lots of visible pixels]

In the `Tree` example, the labels are barely readable. Trying to manually rasterize with a higher resolution (i.e. `Rasterize[%, ImageResolution -> 200]`) doesn't work - the output is still pixelated.

Some questions:

- Can I force Mathematica to render the plots as vector graphics? The engine appears to be perfectly capable of doing so - exporting the graphics to PDF or SVG results in a perfect vector image.
- Is there any way to convince Wolfram Cloud to output higher-resolution images?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), as the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I don't have much experience with the cloud, but if I were looking at this I would wonder if there were a private variable somewhere that controlled the resolution of rasterized output in the cloud, then try to change it and see what happens

Comment: After exhaustive searching, I didn't find anything :( All the desktop DPI settings in `$FrontEnd` don't seem to do anything. Suspecting there's something in the web middleware layer that does extra compression...